# quick question about Drinfeld's 2-page paper "Two Theorems on Modular Curves"

Tags: modular-forms, nt.number-theory

The paper can be found here:

http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01078890.pdf

EDIT: Russian original available at [LINK](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=faa&paperid=2422&option_lang=eng)

In his proof of assertion 1, he "reduces to the case where $x = i\infty$. He says that for any $g\in M$ and $\gamma\in\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, there is some $h\in\Gamma(N)$ such that $g\gamma(i\infty) = \gamma h(i\infty)$.

How does he get that?

Also, this he says in his proof of assertion 2 that via the Petersson inner product, $\|\omega\| = \|\omega|_g\|$ for all $g\in M$ implies that $\omega|_g = \omega$ for all $g\in M$. He claims this follows from the triangle inequality.

I don't see why $\|\omega\| = \|\omega|_g\|$ (since $g$ has determinant $p$, isn't $\|\omega|_g\| = p^2\|\omega\|$?)

I also don't see why this implies that $\omega|_g = \omega$.

I've been stuck on this for a while.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

- will

Comment: Regarding assertion 1, first do the case $\gamma=1$. Regarding assertion 2, the Petersson scalar product is defined using the hyperbolic metric $\frac{dx \cdot dy}{y^2}$ which is invariant under $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{R})_+$, not only $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Theorem 2.3, page 64 in Lang's book "Introduction to Modular forms".